# Exchange 2013 rejecting emails

Tags: exchange-2013

I have Exchange 2013 running on Server 2012. It has started to reject quite a lot of inbound emails. I collect them with EFS on the same server and send them via SMTP. EFS shows that the emails are rejected - it doesn't say why. Some of these are regular text emails - nothing odd about them. If I send an email from my gmail it always works. Other emails work. In an ideal world I would like all emails to appear in my exchange mailbox - I will worry about filtering spam and virus content.

Why is Exchange rejecting the emails and is there a way to tell it to pass all emails through?

At request here is the header from a rejected email

```
Return-Path: <web-filing@companies-house.gov.uk>
Received: from ws-mail1.companieshouse.gov.uk (ws-mail1.companieshouse.gov.uk [194.75.36.66]) by mail.softsyshosting.com with SMTP;
   Sat, 14 Oct 2017 04:29:29 -0600
Reply-to: web-filing@companies-house.gov.uk
Subject: (CS01) Confirmation statement received for XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX
Date: Sat, 14 Oct 2017 11:29:04 +0100
Message-ID: <CHCOMM.3047917614.3049232551.XXXXXX@companies-house.gov.uk>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="Message-Boundary-by-Mail-Sender-1507976943"
X-SmarterMail-Spam: SPF_Pass, HostKarma - Whitelist, ISpamAssassin 0 [raw: 0], DK_None, DKIM_None
X-SmarterMail-TotalSpamWeight: -6
X-Forwarder: Redirected by EFS, http://www.chimeracomputing.com/
To: accounts@xxxxxxxxxxx.com
From: Companies House <web-filing@companies-house.gov.uk>
```

Comment: Can it be a EFS error ? as usually exchanhe don't reject by default unless a error in the mail itselft

Comment: Do you have the header from a rejected email? This would be VERY helpfull if you can post it here.

Comment: It does seem to be an exchange issue. Following up on your EFS comment, I installed Hexamail. It sees more of the error: "Next server responded with error: 451 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX2 15/10/2017 13:50:35 Message: Queuing email <POP335B94__B358__72_18_XXX_XX_110> for retry". It does deliver it later though